# ftp appends ^M to .Z file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp, compression

I am doing `ftp` in binary mode and downloading some compressed_file.Z but I get compressed_file.Z^M and when I am using `dos2unix` it creates a new file with `^M` removed but still when I try to uncompress it, I get error saying `Corrupt Input` or `its not recognized as tar file` etc. If I paste it in my windows machine using filezila, I am able to open it with 7Z. I have also used `sed 's/^M$//' compressed_file.dmp.Z^M>compressed_file.dmp.Z` but still it is corrupt file. Has someone faced similar issue?

Comment: Ouch ! be careful not to perform sed or dos2unix operations on binary files, it is very very likely that some legit ^M characters will get removed, making your file corrupted beyond repair.

Comment: well its not recognized as `uncompress compressed_file.dmp` return corrupt file

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that it's only your filenames that contains ^M at the end. You could rename them with:

```
for A in *.Z$'\x0d'; do
    mv -i "$A" "${A%?}"  # Remove -i to skip confirmation
done
```

Comment: thanks for help, I didn't require to try this as I specified nothing in place of the binary type of mode it worked fine. Though in future it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Removing specification of any kind of mode say ASCII or BINARY etc solved my problem.